# How can I use JavaScript to take content from a textarea and print it to a docx file?

Tags: javascript, html, input, output, docx

I am trying to make a html to take something I have typed in the textarea and print in out in a docx file. Any ideas?

I tried a library DOCX but couldn't get my hand around it. And I also tried mammoth.js.

```
import { Document, Packer } from "docx";

function saveToDocx() {
  var content = document.getElementById("content").value;

  // Create a new document
  const doc = new Document();
  doc.addParagraph(content);

  // Generate the DOCX file
  Packer.toBlob(doc).then((blob) => {
    // Create a temporary link to download the DOCX file
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = "output.docx";
    link.click();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before handing you the solution, I would like to show you some approaches.

Firstly, know how to attain the value of an input component based on the library / framework that you are using.

Secondly, whenever you are using a package that you don't know yet, make sure to give yourself time to make yourself familiar with the package and how it is used.

Lastly, when writing your code, try to abstract all your functionalities in different functions so you have smaller pieces of code which are testable.

The correct link to the package documentation can be found through https://www.npmjs.com/package/docx which also holds an example in the readme file.

```
import { Document, HeadingLevel, Packer, Paragraph } from 'docx'

const toDocxBlob = async (value: string) => {
  const document = new Document({
    sections: [
      {
        children: [new Paragraph({ text: value, heading: HeadingLevel.HEADING_1 })]
      }
    ]
  })

  const blob = await Packer.toBlob(document)
  return blob
}
```

Separate your download into a usable component.

```
const downloadContent = (content: Blob, fileName: string, fileExtension: string) => {
  const element = document.createElement('a')
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(content)
  element.href = url
  element.download = `${fileName}${fileExtension}`
  element.click()
}
```

Underneath I provided a React handout.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

interface FormProps {
  onSubmit: (text: string) => void;
}

const Form: React.FC<FormProps> = ({ onSubmit }) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const blob = await toDocxBlob(text);
    downloadContent(blob, 'file', 'docx')
  };

  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    setText(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <textarea
        rows={4}
        placeholder="Enter your text"
        value={text}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">
        Download in docx format
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Form;
```